# PyBind11: binding a function that uses double pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pybind11

I would like to bind a C++-function with PyBind11. The problem is that this functions has an argument with a double pointer and the compiler raises an error

`error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char **' with an rvalue of type 'typename make_caster<char **>::cast_op_type<typename std::add_rvalue_reference<char**>::type>' (aka 'char *')`.

Specifically the code look like this:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

#include <iostream>

namespace py = pybind11;

void parse_args(int argn__, char** argv__)
{
  for(int i = 1; i < argn__; ++i)
    {
      std::cout<< argv__[i];
    }
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(argv_bind, m) {
   m.def("parse_args", &parse_args);     
}
```

Comment: Probably pybind11 can't decide what python class is equivalent to the double pointer. How would the python code provide the double pointer to the c++ extension? The python side can instead give a numpy array or python list, which are translated to `py::array`, Eigen array, or `std::list` at the c++ side. By the way, python's `sys.argv` and `argparse` already can parse command line arguments. You can use those and pass the result to c++ extension by `bool`, `std::string`, `int`, etc.  Since parsing commandline arguments is not performance critical, python can do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For non-simple argument types (e.g. like your `char **`) you'll have to wrap the function itself, where your wrapper provides the logic to go from a simpler type or a Python object to the desired type.

In this case, `char *` are actually a pretty unsafe type to work with, since it doesn't get memory cleanup; to make this work robustly you'll need to take `std::string`s, from which you can then access the `char *` via the `c_str()` method.  (In pybind11, even when you take `char *` arguments, those are really just pointers into `std::string` arguments: the Python API deliberately *doesn't* let callers access the internal storage of Python strings).

So then you just want to combine it with a type that can itself expose the whole thing as a `char **`, which is pretty much what `std::vector` is designed to do.  Here's a wrapper that would fit your example code:

```
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

m.def("parse_args", [](std::vector<std::string> args) {
    std::vector<char *> cstrs;
    cstrs.reserve(args.size());
    for (auto &s : args) cstrs.push_back(const_cast<char *>(s.c_str()));
    return parse_args(cstrs.size(), cstrs.data());
});
```

(If your `parse_args` actually takes a `const char **` you can drop the `const_cast`).

Comment: I would appreciate if you could take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039323/4999991) as well. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Jason's answer could cause undefined behavior because it is taking away the const-ness of `c_str()` with the `const_char`, i.e., `const_cast<char *>(s.c_str())`. So in his case `cstrs` should really be `std::vector<const char*>` so the `const_char` can be removed.

However, `parse_args` usually expects `char**` rather than `const char* const*`. Thus, a more correct alternative would be:

```
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

m.def("parse_args", [](std::vector<std::string> args) {
    std::vector<char *> cstrs;
    cstrs.reserve(args.size());
    for (std::vector& s : args) cstrs.push_back(&s[0]); // s.data() valid since C++11
    return parse_args(cstrs.size(), cstrs.data());
});
```