# The correct CMakeLists.txt file to call a MAXON libarary in a Python script using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, linux, cmake, pybind11

I'm very new to the whole CMake. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59938992/4999991) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59968956/4999991) posts, now I want to call a MAXON function inside Python, using pybind11. What I have done so far:

- The library can be downloaded from [this page](https://www.maxongroup.com/maxon/view/product/control/Positionierung/541718) ([direct download link](https://www.maxongroup.com/medias/sys_master/root/8837358518302/EPOS-Linux-Library-En.zip)).

```
wget https://www.maxongroup.com/medias/sys_master/root/8837358518302/EPOS-Linux-Library-En.zip
```

- unzip:

```
unzip EPOS-Linux-Library-En.zip
```

- make the install shell script executable and run it:

```
chmod +x ./install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

- Then going to the example folder:

```
cd /opt/EposCmdLib_6.6.1.0/examples/HelloEposCmd/
```

- Now combining the `CMakeLists.txt` files from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59968956/4999991):

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project (HelloEposCmd)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall")

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
pybind11_add_module(${PROJECT_NAME} HelloEposCmd.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} HelloEposCmd.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} -lEposCmd)
```

- and the `HelloEposCmd.cpp` this line is added right after other header files:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
```

the main function is renamed to:

```
int run(int argc, char** argv)
```

and the pybind11 syntax to add the module is written at the end:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(HelloEposCmd, m) {

    m.def("run", &run, "runs the HelloEposCmd");
}
```

However, When I run the `cmake .` I get the error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_executable):
>
> add_executable can not create target "HelloEposCmd" because another target with the same name already exists. The existing target is a module library created in source directory "/opt/EposCmdLib_6.6.1.0/examples/HelloEposCmd" See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
>
> ...

I was wondering if you could be kind to help me get the right `CMakeList.txt` file. Ideally, I should be able to call the compiled module in python:

```
# HelloEposCmd.py

import HelloEposCmd

HelloEposCmd.run()
```

Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`pybind11_add_module` already creates a target for you. So you don't need `add_executable` anymore. Just remove that line and when you will build you will get a library with the name `HelloEposCmd`

`add_executable` is needed if you are building an executable (.exe), which I believe is not what you want.

[Documenation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html) of pybind11 says.

> This function behaves very much like CMake’s builtin add_library (in fact, it’s a wrapper function around that command).

Comment: now I get another error: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (target_link_libraries) the keyword signature ...`

Comment: you don't need that line too. It is needed to link libraries when your are building an executable.

Comment: are you sure?! because when I remove this it compiles but when running the code we get segmentations fault errors.

Comment: when you build do you get `HelloEposCmd` library?

Comment: check the cmake example from the pybind11 documentation [here](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: removing those two last lines the `cmake .` works. However, when running `make` I get the `error: can not convert ... char**` which has to do with pybind11 as I'm reading [here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/417#issuecomment-248150544). I need to find a workaround. for example if I could understand what are the default values for `int argc` and `char** argv` then I could just define them as variables inside the `run` function.

Comment: as a simple example, I'm actually using my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59968956/4999991).

Comment: as you pointed out char** is not supported by pybind11. What is it that you want to do with your run function? rewrite the signature of your run function so that it doesn't use char**. btw because the issue is now not related to cmake any more you should close this post

Comment: actually I think it is still partly cmake problem. What I did as I suggested above I defined argc and argv as variables inside the run function. except I defined `char* argv[] = {"HelloEposCmd"}` and I get only a warning while compiling. but then when running the python code it errors out that `undefined symbol: VCS_ActiveProfilePositionMode`, which I think is because we did not link against the right maxon library files.

Comment: solved it. will write another post. tldr the last like of the cmake file should be written according to [this](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1527#issuecomment-423652505)

Comment: how do you think about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039323/4999991)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [abhilb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428102/abhilb) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60038560/4999991) and his kind followup in the comments I was able to figure the problem out. well, at least find a temporary workaround:

- According to [this post](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1527#issuecomment-423652505), the last two lines of the `CMakeLists.txt` file should change to

```
# this line can be removed
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} HelloEposCmd.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -lEposCmd)
```

- and then because according to [this post](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/417#issuecomment-248150544) pybind11 doesn't support double pointers we change the run function to:

```
int run() {

    int argc = 1;
    char* argv[] = {"./HelloEposCmd"};

...
}
```

which I suppose to be a horrible workaround (inspired by information from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean/3024202)). Now running `cmake .`, `make` and `python3 HelloEposCmd.py` should work properly (except a small c++ warning!).

**P.S.1.** Maybe someone could use `std::vector<std::string>` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471134/4999991). This idea was proposed here and there are already some answers worth investigating.

**P.S.2.** Following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60047957/4999991), another workaround could be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myFunc(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}

int run(int argc, long* argv_) {

    char** argv = (char**)malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        argv[i] = (char*)(argv_[i]);
    }

    myFunc(argc, argv);

    free(argv);

    return 0;
}
```