# passing a list of strings from python to C through pybind11

Tags: python, c, pybind11

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039323/4999991), I want to know how I can pass a list of strings from Python to C (i.e., using C headers and syntax, not C++), through Pybind11. I'm completely aware of the fact that Pybind11 is a C++ library and codes must be compiled by a C++ compiler anyway. However, it is difficult for me to understand the C++ implementations, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60049141/4999991) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048102/4999991).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/ac170ada8aeaec4a73842a5eba6e1179) I tried to pass a python list of strings by pointers, represented as integers, and then receive them by `long*` in C, but it didn't work.

The C/C++ code should be something like:

```
// example.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int run(/*<pure C or pybind11 datatypes> args*/){

    // if pybind11 data types are used convert them to pure C :
    // int argc = length of args
    // char* argv[] =  array of pointers to the strings in args, possible malloc

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    } 

    // possible free

    return 0;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {

    m.def("run", &run, "runs the example");
}
```

A simple `CMakeLists.txt` example is also provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59968956/4999991). and the Python code can be something like this:

```
#example.py
import example

print(example.run(["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]))
```

To avoid misunderstandings like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60047957/4999991), please consider these points:

- This is not an XY question, as the presumed Y problem has already been solved in the correct/canonical way using C++ headers/standard libraries and syntax (links above). The purpose of this question is pure curiosity. Solving the problem in a syntax I'm familiar with will help me to understand the underlying nature of pybind11 data types and functionality. Please do not try to find the Y problem and solve it.
- I'm completely aware that pybind11 is a C++ library and the code must be compiled with a C++ compiler anyway.
- I would appreciate it if you would consult me in the comments about required edits to my question, rather than doing it yourself. I know you want to help, but I have tried to frame my question as nicely as possible to avoid confusion.
- I would appreciate it if you would avoid changing the none commented parts of my C/C++ and python codes, as much as possible.
- I'm aware that using the term "C/C++" is wrong. I use the term to refer to a C++ code written in C syntax and using C headers. I'm sorry that I don't know a better way to call it.
- As the commented parts of the `example.cpp` file indicates, it is ok to use pybind11 datatypes and then convert them to C. But I suspect a pure C solution might also be possible. For example, see [this attempt](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/ac170ada8aeaec4a73842a5eba6e1179).

Comment: `the code must be compiled with a C++` - so write a short wrapper that takes `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` and converts it to `char **`

Comment: @KamilCuk that's actually what most of the existing solutions have done. Please consider that I want to use only C syntax, headers and standard library.

Comment: @KamilCuk It is ok to use pybind11 datatypes like `py::list` and then convert them to pure C.

Comment: Conversion of C++ data types to structures that C code can understand, is not possible in a portable way.  You'd have to understand how your specific C++ compiler and linker organize objects in memory, and even then, it's not trivial.

Comment: I would also add that these formats change with different compiler and linker settings, as well as across versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I've reformatted the [previous example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60049141/4999991) where I used C++ constructs, to only use C and pybind11 ones.

```js
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x03000000
#define MyPyText_AsString PyString_AsString
#else
#define MyPyText_AsString PyUnicode_AsUTF8
#endif

namespace py = pybind11;

int run(py::object pyargv11) {
int argc = 0;
char** argv = NULL;

PyObject* pyargv = pyargv11.ptr();
if (PySequence_Check(pyargv)) {
    Py_ssize_t sz = PySequence_Size(pyargv);
    argc = (int)sz;

    argv = (char**)malloc(sz * sizeof(char*));
    for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        PyObject* item = PySequence_GetItem(pyargv, i);
        argv[i] = (char*)MyPyText_AsString(item);
        Py_DECREF(item);
        if (!argv[i] || PyErr_Occurred()) {
            free(argv);
            argv = nullptr;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!argv) {
    //fprintf(stderr,  "argument is not a sequence of strings\n");
    //return;

    if (!PyErr_Occurred())
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "could not convert input to argv");
    throw py::error_already_set();
}

for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", argv[i]);

free(argv);

return 0;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
m.def("run", &run, "runs the example");
}
```

Below I will heavily comment it out to explain what I'm doing and why.

In Python2, string objects are `char*` based, in Python3, they are Unicode based. Hence the following macro `MyPyText_AsString` that changes behavior based on Python version, since we need to get to C-style "char*".

```cpp
#if PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x03000000
#define MyPyText_AsString PyString_AsString
#else
#define MyPyText_AsString PyUnicode_AsUTF8
#endif
```

The pyargv11 `py::object` is a thin handle on a Python C-API handle object; since the following code makes use of the Python C-API, it's easier to deal with the underlying `PyObject*` directly.

```cpp
void closed_func_wrap(py::object pyargv11) {
    int argc = 0;            // the length that we'll pass
    char** argv = NULL;      // array of pointers to the strings

    // convert input list to C/C++ argc/argv :

    PyObject* pyargv = pyargv11.ptr();
```

The code will only accept containers that implement the sequence protocol and can thus be looped over. This covers the two most important ones `PyTuple` and `PyList` at the same time (albeit a tad slower than checking for those types directly, but this will keep the code more compact). To be fully generic, this code should also check for the iterator protocol (e.g. for generators and probably reject str objects, but both are unlikely.

```cpp
    if (PySequence_Check(pyargv)) {
```

Okay, we have a sequence; now get its size. (This step is the reason why for ranges you'd need to use the Python iterator protocol since their size is typically not known (although you can request a hint).)

```cpp
        Py_ssize_t sz = PySequence_Size(pyargv);
```

One part, the size is done, store it in the variable that can be passed on to other functions.

```cpp
        argc = (int)sz;
```

Now allocate the array of pointers to `char*` (technically `const char*`,but that matters not here as we'll cast it away).

```cpp
        argv = (char**)malloc(sz * sizeof(char*));
```

Next, loop over the sequence to retrieve the individual elements.

```cpp
        for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
```

This gets a single elemenent from the sequence. The GetItem call is equivalent to Pythons "[i]", or **getitem** call.

```cpp
            PyObject* item = PySequence_GetItem(pyargv, i);
```

In Python2, string objects are char* based, in Python3, they are unicode based. Hence the following macro "MyPyText_AsString" that changes behavior based on Python version, since we need to get to C-style "char*".

The cast from `const char*` to `char*` here is in principle safe, but the contents of `argv[i]` must NOT be modified by other functions. The same is true for the `argv` argument of a `main()`, so I'm assuming that to be the case.

Note that the C string is NOT copied. The reason is that in Py2, you simply get access to the underlying data and in Py3, the converted string is kept as a data member of the Unicode object and Python will do the memory management. In both cases, we are guaranteed that their lifetimes will be at least as long as the lifetime as the input Python object (pyargv11), so at least for the duration of this function call. If other functions decide to keep pointers, copies would be needed.

```cpp
            argv[i] = (char*)MyPyText_AsString(item);
```

The result of `PySequence_GetItem` was a new reference, so now that we're done with it, drop it:

```cpp
            Py_DECREF(item);
```

It is possible that the input array did not contain only Python str objects. In that case, the conversion will fail and we need to check for that case, or "closed_function" may segfault.

```cpp
            if (!argv[i] || PyErr_Occurred()) {
```

Clean up the memory previously allocated.

```cpp
                free(argv);
```

Set argv to `NULL` for success checking later on:

```cpp
                argv = nullptr;
```

Give up on the loop:

```cpp
                break;
```

If the given object was not a sequence, or if one of the elements of the sequence was not a string, then we don't have an `argv` and so we bail:

```cpp
    if (!argv) {
```

The following is a bit lazy, but probably better to understand if all you want to look at is C code.

```cpp
        fprintf(stderr,  "argument is not a sequence of strings\n");
        return;
```

What you should really do, is check whether an error was already set (e.g. b/c of a conversion problem) and set one if not. Then notify pybind11 of it. This will give you a clean Python exception on the caller's end. This goes like so:

```cpp
        if (!PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "could not convert input to argv");
        throw py::error_already_set();       // by pybind11 convention.
```

Alright, if we get here, then we have an `argc` and `argv`, so now we can use them:

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", argv[i]);
```

Finally, clean up the allocated memory.

```cpp
    free(argv);
```

### Notes:

- I would still advocate for the use of at least `std::unique_ptr` as that makes life so much easier in case there are C++ exceptions thrown (from custom converters of any input object).
- I was originally expecting to be able to replace all of the code with the one-liner `std::vector<char*> pv{pyargv.cast<std::vector<char*>>()};` after `#include <pybind11/stl.h>`, but I found that that does not work (even as it does compile). Neither did using `std::vector<std::string>` (also compiles, but also fails at run-time).

Just ask if anything is still unclear.

**EDIT**: If you truly only want to have a PyListObject, just call `PyList_Check(pyargv11.ptr())` and if true, cast the result: `PyListObject* pylist = (PyListObject*)pyargv11.ptr()`. Now, if you want to work with `py::list`, you can also use the following code:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x03000000
#define MyPyText_AsString PyString_AsString
#else
#define MyPyText_AsString PyUnicode_AsUTF8
#endif

namespace py = pybind11;

int run(py::list inlist) {
    int argc = (int)inlist.size();
    char** argv = (char**)malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        argv[i] = (char*)MyPyText_AsString(inlist[i].ptr());

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", argv[i]);

    free(argv);

    return 0;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("run", &run, "runs the example");
}
```

This code is shorter only b/c it has less functionality: it only accepts lists and it also is more clunky in error handling (eg. it will leak if passed in a list of integers due to pybind11 throwing an exception; to fix that, use unique_ptr as in the very first example code so that argv is freed on exception).

Comment: thanks a lot man. you are awsome. mind if I reformat your post so it is more readable for me? unfortunately it will apply my edits without asking for your peer review. but you can revert or reedit any part you don't like.

Comment: I reformatted the post for better readability. I hope you don't mind it.

Comment: I have lots of questions, but if you don't mind I want to start with this: 1. why my attempt [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/ac170ada8aeaec4a73842a5eba6e1179) doesn't work? why I can't pass a python list of strings to C by poiters and reading it over there by `long*`?

Comment: also, I don't think that you have defined `item`, I think you forgot to use `PySequence_GetItem`.

Comment: Definition of 'item' was there in the original code. Both for the use with `PySequence_GetItem` and for the needed `Py_DECREF` later (which is not needed in `PyList_GetItem` that you used, as that returns a borrowed reference). The code you linked works "as is", so I guess I'm looking at a version newer than your comment. I really recommend retaining the error handling, though. Using a `long*` won't work b/c you first need to get out of pybind11, which doesn't appear to have a good converter for you.

Comment: Yes, I did update the Gist based on your code, and the error handling stuff I removed just to help understand the main functionality. Next step I want to replace the `py::object` with Cpython `PyListObject` if possible.

Comment: would you be kind to reedit your post and add the missing part? Also what I have in the GitHub Gist has a bug/issue. It prints one extra slice of memory.

Comment: Re-edited and made some notes about using Python `list` and added a py::list example code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you have already helped me a lot. Mind if I keep bothering you witth more questions?

Comment: Sure; or open a new one if this wall of text gets too long. If it has "pybind11" in there, I'll come across it soon enough.